# Is it a bad idea to use mutable for pre-allocated temporaries?

Tags: c++, const, mutable

Let us assume I have the following C++ class:

```
class MyFastMessageEncoder
{
public:
    MyFastMessageEncoder() :
        m_fieldEncoder(ENCODING_STYLE_DEFAULT)
    {
    }

    void set_encoding_style(const EncodingStyle encodingStyle)
    {
        m_fieldEncoder.set_encoding_style(encodingStyle);
    }

    EncodingStyle get_encoding_style() const
    {
        return m_fieldEncoder.get_encoding_style();
    }

    void encode(const UnencodedFieldList &unencodedFieldList, Message &message
    {
        for (UnencodedFieldList::const_iterator it = unencodedFieldList.begin(), end = unencodedFieldList.end(); it != end; ++it)
        {
            m_fieldEncoder.set_raw_data(*it);
            message.add_field(m_fieldEncoder.encode());
        }
    }

private:
    FieldEncoder    m_fieldEncoder;
};
```

The `MyFastMessageEncoder` class is required to be extremely efficient (encoding will be performed on tens of thousands of messages per second), the time required to instantiate the `FieldEncoder` object is a non-negligible cost, so to solve the issue, I have defined the `FieldEncoder` object as a class member, and initialized it inside the constructor just once.

My issue is that `FieldEncoder::SetRawData()` is a non-const method, which means that the `MyFastMessageEncoder::encode` method must also be non-const. *However*, if I were to make the FieldEncoder object a temporary inside the method, `MyFastMessageEncoder::encode` could be flagged as const. This means that every object that calls  `MyFastMessageEncoder::encode` is also non-const, which (to me) just starts ruining the program's const-correctness.

Now I understand how the `mutable` keyword works works, and how I could use it to solve this problem, but my question is: **Would doing so be considered bad form, since the internals of the object are technically being modified?**

Other considerations:

- Thread-safety is not a concern, this is guaranteed to only run in a single thread (although the `MyFastMessageEncoder` may be created on multiple threads)
- The `set_raw_data` method does not impact the `FieldEncoder` class outside the `MyFastMessageEncoder::encode` method. Any data that is set is cleared or overwritten the next time the `set_raw_data` method is called.

Comment: When you're dealing in these kinds of micro-optimizations, doesn't good taste essentially go out the window anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah that's pretty much what I'm coming to accept, I'm just lost as to which of the two I'd consider the lesser-of-two-evils :(

Comment: Make the member a function argument. const problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If encoding depends on previous fields, then `MyFastMessageEncoder::encode` is obviously non-const as it changes the observable state of the instance - calling it twice won't give the same result, therefore the state of the instance has changed, therefore it should be non-const.

Otherwise it seems a bit odd that you have, in the `FieldEncoder`, both a costly initialisation and that the state following `set_raw_data` is governed only by the data that's set. This suggests to me that the initialisation cost might be reduced - either sharing some of whatever structures are set up, or by pooling encoders.

However, both of those refactorings would be much more involved than making the encoder mutable, so if the initialisation cost is not causing problems elsewhere I would comment that the encoder only exists as a member as an optimisation for `encode` and make it mutable.

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for your response! My example is quite simplified to try and get my point across, but I see what you're saying. Unfortunately the `FieldEncoder` object itself is part of a 3rd party library that I can't change, and their advice is to pre-allocate the encoding object(s). So this question is based more around their advice than my design. The `encode` method of the `MyFastMessageEncoder` class does not change the observable state, it simply encodes the data passed to it and packs it, so if the Encoder were declared as a temp, it would definitely be const.

Comment: Your thought about pooling is interesting though, it might just work!